# date format in node to generate pdf

Tags: node.js, angular, date, pdf, report

I am generating report i.e pdf from node to front end.
I need to get a date with the format of dd/MM/yyyy .
I used this :

```
<td style="font-size:11px;text-align: center;">
        <strong>
        <%= new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);%>
        </strong>
</td>
```

to get a date but the report show in the format of yyyy-mm-dd.
I need a perfect solution to get the date format as dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to format a JavaScript date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3552461/how-to-format-a-javascript-date)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the best solution, I would recommend you to use [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/). example above:

```
const moment = require('moment');
const formattedDate = moment().format('DD/MM/YYYY');
```

If you want to leave the logic with pure JS, you can do this like following:

```js
const date = new Date().toISOString().slice(0, 10);
const [yyyy,mm,dd] = date.split('-');
const formattedDate = `${dd}/${mm}/${yyyy}`;
console.log(formattedDate);
```

Comment: @ IgorLitvinovich Thank you. I went with moment.js.